# How to find the lowest value in a data frame matching specific criterias and return a specific column

Tags: r

Firstly, I'm pretty new to R and I'm also new with asking questions on SO, so bear with me if I'm asking stupid questions or am not following SO conventions.

I'm trying to find the best subscription type for multiple users based on their former calling behaviour. Until now I've managed to approx. match 98'000 rows to calculate the effective costs with a (variable) number of subscription types.

[image: effective costs]

There's also a data frame with the predicted costs per subscription type for every month: 
[image: predicted costs]

Now I'm trying to find the best subscription type where the costs are lower than the current one for every user and month. I'll do a merge to show which results I'd expect:

[image: comparison]

So, in month `2019-01` the costs of `subscription_2` are lower than the current subscription for `User1`, therefore `subscription2` should be the recommendation. For months `2019-02` and `2019-03` there is no recommendation as there are no subscription types with lower costs.

For `User2` subscription type `subscription_3` should be the recommendation in all months, since these costs are always lower than the current subscription.

I'm currently following the courses on DataCamp.com and I am pretty sure that this is almost certainly a VERY basic action in `r`, but I need someone to guide me into the right direction.

This is what I have so far:

```
library(dplyr)

effective.costs <- data.frame(
  user = c(rep("User1", 3), rep("User2", 3)),
  month = c(rep(c("2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03"), 2)),
  current_subscription = c(rep("subscription_1", 3), rep("subscription_2", 3)),
  costs = c(70, 20, 50, 150, 130, 170)
)

predicted.costs <- data.frame(
  user = c(rep("User1", 9), rep("User2", 9)),
  month = c(rep("2019-01",3), rep("2019-02", 3), rep("2019-03", 3)),
  subscription = c(rep(c("subscription_1", "subscription_2", "subscription_3"), 6)),
  calculated_costs = c(
    c(70, 50, 110, 20, 50, 70, 50, 80, 120), 
    c(190, 150, 110, 210, 130, 110, 250, 170, 110)
    )
)

comparison <- merge(effective.costs, predicted.costs, by = c("user", "month"))

getRecommendation <- function(x) {
  subscription <- predicted.costs %>% 
    filter(
      calculated_costs < x['costs'] & 
      user == x['user'] & 
      month == x['month']
    ) %>%
    arrange(calculated_costs) %>%
    select(subscription) 
  subscription <- ifelse(
    length(subscription) > 0, 
    as.character(subscription[1, 1]), 
    NA
  )
  # I know return is not needed, but I'm used to it... :-)
  return(subscription)
}

effective.costs$recommendation <- apply(effective.costs, 1, getRecommendation)

View(effective.costs)
```

The most important part here is probably the function `getRecommendation`:

```
getRecommendation <- function(x) {
  subscription <- predicted.costs %>% 
    filter(
      calculated_costs < x['costs'] & 
      user == x['user'] & 
      month == x['month']
    ) %>%
    arrange(calculated_costs) %>%
    select(subscription) 
  subscription <- ifelse(
    length(subscription) > 0, 
    as.character(subscription[1, 1]), 
    NA
  )
  # I know return is not needed, but I'm used to it... :-)
  return(subscription)
}
```

which I'm trying to `apply` to every row in  `effective.costs`:

```
effective.costs$recommendation <- apply(effective.costs, 1, getRecommendation)
```

While this gives me the correct output for `User2`, I currently believe this to be coincident since there's no recommendation for `User1`, even if there should be one for month `2019-01`:

[image: wrong result]

Could someone please push me into the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: Apologies, but I thought that's what I did? The first few lines of the code are creating the "dummy" data as shown in the screen shots... What else would you expect me to do? ;-)

Comment: Sorry mate, not sure how I missed that! :)

Comment: @Martin - see edit below. Your function does not behave because ```apply``` coerces everything into a character. That makes numeric comparisons difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does away with the `apply` and the `getRecommendation` function. `R` is vectorized so we should try to think column-wise as much as we can.

```
comparison <- merge(effective.costs, predicted.costs, by = c("user", "month"))

comparison%>%
  mutate(net_savings = calculated_costs-costs)%>%
  group_by(user, month)%>%
  filter(net_savings == min(net_savings))%>%
  slice(1) #for ties
```

The issue with your `apply()` function is that `apply()` coerces the data.frame to a matrix. A matrix can only have one class type - in this case, you're comparing a number to a string in `calculated_costs < x['costs']`.

Specifically, the evaluation is `calculated_costs < ' 50'` where there is an extra space for 2-digit numbers. For whatever reason, `50 < ' 70'` evaluates `FALSE` whereas `110 < '190'` evaluates `TRUE`.

The solution is to approach the problem differently in this case. There's no need to do rowwise operations via `apply`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution and the explanation on why I failed!!! Now that you mention it I darkly remember having heard this in the DC course... 
Could you explain what the `slice(1)` means at the end?

Comment: It means give me the first row. In this case, since I have group_by, it means give me the first row for each group. It is there in case of ties and sort of aligns with your ```as.character(subscription[1, 1])``` statement.

Comment: Aaah, I think I got it now. I thought this would be covered with `filter(net_savings == min(net_savings))` but `slice(1)` is for the case if there would be two recommended subscriptions with the same costs, which would give me a duplicated row, right? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes. If two prescriptions have the same cost we'd have multiple rows returned for that user month. edit: you probably do away with the net_costs that I made and look directly at costs. I made it more complicated than needed.